# Полностью ли совместим тип bool для С99 и С++?

Tags: c, c++

Например, если взять заголовок функции, которая всегда возвращает true в C99

```
#include <stdbool.h>

extern "C" {
    bool getTrue();
}
```

и подключить в исходник на C++, будет ли это true всегда true в C++?

Comment: А почему бы Вам самому не проэкспериментировать? Можно даже разными компиляторами на разных платформах.

Comment: По-моему, это неверный подход. Я пробую сравнить заголовочный файл stdbool.h с определением bool в C++ и, исходя из этого, сделать вывод, будет ли соответствие.

Comment: Тип bool - целочисленный, char или int. 
false == 0, true == 1
Типы должны приводиться друг ко другу. Все должно стыковаться.

Comment: В Linux gcc typedef char _bool
#define bool _bool

Comment: Тебе говорят про C99, там тип bool это макроопределение для _Bool, который в свою очередь "честный" булевый тип, а вовсе не маскированный int/char

Comment: Честный булевый тип? Это как?

Answer (score 2):

Сильно зависит от компилятора и его опций с которыми будете собирать.
Я считаю, что тут необходим экспериментальный подход - проще проверить будет ли в используемой Вами среде это работать, чем гадать.
В общем же случае вопрос, видимо, не решаем, т.к. стандарт стандартом, а иметь дело будете с конкретными реализациями стандарта в виде конкретных компиляторов. Возможно под разные платформы. И что они будут думать про bool - одному Янусу известно :-)
Скорее же всего работать будет везде, т.к. есть соглашение, что 0 - false, а все остальные целочисленные значения - true, но при этом если

> bool a = true;

то (int)a будет равно 1

Comment: Нашел еще такую информацию:<p>
http://www.rsdn.ru/forum/cpp/65120.aspx<p>
<p>https://developer.mozilla.org/en/C___Portability_Guide
<p>Очень познавательно!

Answer (score 1):

В общем случае говорить про совместимость C99 и C++ нельзя. Лучше использовать определение типа

```
typedef uint8 _bool;
```

чем беспокоиться о совместимости.